# jQuery Tools Validator message position on iPad

Tags: jquery, forms, ipad, validation

I'm using the jQuery tools validator to validate forms on my site, got it all working fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE. I've tested it on the iPhone too and all works fine, until i test it on the iPad!

When you click submit the error tooltip appears but it seems to be at the top of the page and not relative to the form elements, like it is on all the other browsers!

Im using the latest full version of jQuery Tools 1.2.7

Does anyone know of a fix?

Here's my HTML...

```
  <form id="myform" action="/cgi-bin/mailer.pl" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <h3>Enquire About This Holiday</h3>
      <p>Please fill in the form below, items marked with a * require completing.</p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>Full Name *</strong></label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" required="required" class="full" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{3,}" data-message="Error Please Complete" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>Telephone Number *</strong></label>
        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" type="tel" class="full" autocomplete="off"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>E-Mail Address *</strong></label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required="required" class="full" data-message="Error Please Complete" autocomplete="off" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>Which date &amp; ship are you interested in?  *</strong></label>
        <input name="date" id="date" type="text" required="required" class="full" data-message="Error Please Complete" autocomplete="off" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>If applicable which airport will you require?</strong></label>
        <input name="airport" id="airport" type="text" class="full" autocomplete="off" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><strong>Passengers *</strong></label>
        <input name="adults" id="adults" type="text" required="required" class="passengers" data-message="Error Please Complete" size="4" autocomplete="off" />
        Adults
        <input name="kids" id="kids" type="text" class="passengers" size="4" autocomplete="off" />
        Children
      </p>
      <p id="terms"> Please check this box if you do NOT wish to be added to our e-mail list
        <input type="checkbox" name="nomail" id="nomail" value="No" />
      </p>
      <button type="submit">Submit Details</button>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
          <input type="hidden" value="callback-thanks.phtml" name="redirect" />
          <input type="hidden" name="mailerid" value="7" />
          <input type="hidden" name="enquiry" id="enquiry" value="Lewis Test" />
          <input type="hidden" name="affiliate" id="affiliate" value="[INC:displayphoneno("143")]" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
        $("#myform").validator({ 
        position: 'center left',
        offset: [0, -151],
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's already an issue in the jquerytools bug tracker

https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/464

Maybe you'll find more help there